# In Django, what's the difference between verbose_name as a field parameter, and verbose_name in a Meta inner class?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Consider this class:

```
class Product(models.Model):
  name = models.Charfield(verbose_name="Product Name", max_length=255)

  class Meta:
    verbose_name = "Product Name"
```

I looked at the Django docs and it says:

- For `verbose_name` in a **field** declaration: "A human-readable name for the field."
- For `verbose_name` in a **Meta** declaration: "A human-readable name for the object, singular".

When would I see either `verbose_name` manifest at runtime? In a form render? In Django admin?

Comment: `verbose_name in a field declaration` is what you see in your admin when you are creating or editing field or in your form while rendering it in the template.

Comment: `verbose_name in a Meta declaration` is what you see in the admin page.when to use it ? let us say my native language is russian(or other language) but my model name is in english to let the staff of the company to know the model name in the admin  i will use `verbose_name and verbose_name_plural in a Meta declaration` to make it understable.but in general in django admin you will see that it will write the model name in plural by example.

Comment: let us say your model name is `Country` if you do not add `verbose_name_plural='countries' in the meta declaration'` then django by default will add just s in Country and it will be `Countrys` which is not correct.Just an exemple :) sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `verbose_name` in the `Meta` deals with the name of the *model*, not field(s) of that model.

It thus likely should be `'Product'`, not `'Product Name'`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(verbose_name='Product Name', max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product'
```

This thus specifies the table name in the model admin, whereas the `verbose_name` of the field(s) will show up in `ModelForm`s and when you display or edit records.

Answer (score 1):

`verbose_name` in a field declaration is set when the name of that field (here we mean the name) is not enough for the user to explain what that field is exactly. For example, maybe you want to provide a more complete description of the name to the user, suppose you mean a short name. So it is better to set `verbose_name` equal to the "short name".
verbose_name in a Meta declaration is set when you want to show your objects individually in a different way to the user in the admin panel. Of course, we also have `verbose_name_plural` in the meta class. It is used when Django cannot correctly recognize the plural form of a word. Django shows word endings by placing s in plurals, but this is not always true. For example, imagine you have a model called Child. Well, now it is better that you set the `verbose_name_plural` value equal to "children" in the meta class. When you use a language other than English in Django, the above description is more useful.